# How to execute a jax-ws soap request from a string or inputstream

Tags: java, soap, web-services, jax-ws, java-metro-framework

I am using jax-ws ri (metro) and would like to execute a webservice call without an http container. I have an XML file containing the SOAP message (exactly the same as the HTTP POST BODY) and would like to execute in the same virtual machine a soap action. How can I do this?

SOAP MESSAGE AS XML FILE -> WS Endpoint or Port -> SOAP MESSAGE AS XML STRING OR FILE

Has anyone an idea or example?

Thank you,

Maciej

Comment: Is getting the WSDL for the web service not an option?

Answer (score 0):

This may be of assistance?

[CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) provides for "The [Pure XML binding](https://cwiki.apache.org/CXF20DOC/pure-xml.html)  which avoids serialization of a SOAP envelope and just sends a raw XML message."